# Convert Julia data frame column from string to float

Tags: arrays, dataframe, julia

I try to find a simple way to convert a column with type string to float.

I tried some:

```
df[!,x] = parse(Float64, df[!,y])
```

but it doesn't work.

I would be grateful if you have any idea
Thks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to broadcast it (note the `.` after `parse`):

```
julia> df = DataFrame(y = ["1", "2"])
2×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ y      │
│     │ String │
├─────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │
│ 2   │ 2      │

julia> df.x = parse.(Float64, df.y)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0

julia> df
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ y      │ x       │
│     │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 1.0     │
│ 2   │ 2      │ 2.0     │
```

an alternative using `transform!` would be (it is more verbose in this case):

```
julia> transform!(df, :y => ByRow(x -> parse(Float64, x)) => :x)
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ y      │ x       │
│     │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 1.0     │
│ 2   │ 2      │ 2.0     │
```

If you have `missing` values in `:y` replace `parse` by `passmissing(parse)` in the codes above, e.g.

```
df.x = passmissing(parse).(Float64, df.y)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried your proposal before without success, but the problem was I had some missing values in the column y. After filling the values, it works fine. Interested if it is possible to do the all thing in one line of code ?

Comment: sure - I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thks a lot !